# Deploying Google Cloud Spanner within .jinja file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-storage, jinja2, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to create `.yaml` and `.jinja` files for a full cloud deployment, but have become stuck with deploying Cloud spanner, I am aware that it is a PaaS Application, so how would such application be implemented if it can at all?

I am relatively new to this area and am currently experimenting with cloud technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Spanner does not require a configuration file for deployment. You can create a new Cloud Spanner instance using the Google Cloud Console UI and point your application to it. Follow the instructions in: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/create-manage-instances